# How to send table name as Mysql Store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I write a store procedure.But it don't take the table name as a parameter.Now how i send a table name as aparameter.Pls see my proc below:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `db_test`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_proc`(IN newsInfoTable VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN              
    SELECT news INTO @news
    FROM newsInfoTable
    WHERE CURDATE()=DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') 
    ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1;
    SELECT @news;
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Calling parameter:

```
USE db_test;
CALL test_proc('tbl_news_list');
```

**But the ERROR is: Table 'db_test.newsinfotable' doesn't exist**

How solve this problem.Pls help.

Comment: you've already asked this question, it has been answered and you accepted the answer, how is this question different from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609778/mysql-store-procedure-dont-take-table-name-as-parameter

Comment: dear Johan,thanks for your concern.But i getting error when i write the full proc.in the sence of example that working fine thats why i accept the answer.but here i get the error on '(char) when use date_time function.So i want for a better solution.Hope you withdrow your negative vote.

Comment: looking at this question and the duplicate as well as the accepted answer, this is a true duplicate, because you did not include any info from the accepted answer in this question. Your latest question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612530/error-when-send-table-as-parameter-in-mysql-store-procedure does use the correct way of doing things, so that's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) in your procedure body:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ... FROM ', newsInfoTable);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
//.....
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Your code should look like :

```
SET @sql_stam = CONCAT('SELECT news INTO @news FROM ',newsInfoTable,  
 ' WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_time,\'%Y-%m-%d\') 
ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1');
...
SELECT @news;
```

Also, I don't see any reasons you need to use `@news` variable...

Comment: thanks.But when i use DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') in my prepair statement then the '(sign) getting error.So,what can i do now??

Comment: Dear @a1ex07:Thx for your time.i write a proc .it's execute properly but getting and error when call the procedure: Error Code : 1327
Undeclared variable: Third.Please see my procedure and give me a solution:    DELIMITER $$
USE `db_dailystar`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_proc`(IN newsInfoTable VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN     
    SET @sql_stam = CONCAT('SELECT news INTO ', @news,' FROM ',newsInfoTable,' WHERE ',CURDATE(),'=?;');      
    PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_stam;     
    SET @where_param = DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d');     
    EXE

Comment: @riad: you better update your question. it's hard to read your code in comment.

Comment: pls see my question on:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612530/error-when-send-table-as-parameter-in-mysql-store-procedure

Comment: Dear @ a1ex07: many thanks for your time pls see my question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612530/error-when-send-table-as-parameter-in-mysql-store-procedure i have a confident you can help to to solve the problem.so pls help.i use your updated question but getting the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select @news; END' at line 9

Comment: @riad let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1220/discussion-between-a1ex07-and-riad)