# ERROR when send table as parameter in MySQL store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I wrote a store procedure. It executes properly, but when I call the procedure, it shows the error:

> Error Code : 1327 Undeclared variable:
>   Third

Please see my procedure below:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `db_test`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_proc`(IN newsInfoTable VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN     
    SET @sql_stam = CONCAT('SELECT news INTO ', @news,' FROM ',newsInfoTable,' WHERE ',CURDATE(),'=?;');      
    PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_stam;     
    SET @where_param = DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d');     
    EXECUTE s1 USING @where_param;    
    SELECT @news;          
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Calling parameter:

```
USE db_test;
CALL test_proc('tbl_morning_news');
```

Comment: i m not getting the solution..pls try to understand..johan.i m in serious trable.If you can pls help me to solve the problem or give me the chance to get the solution

Comment: it's a bit hard to tell your questions apart. If you want to ask a follow up question on another question. I would advice you to take the time to refer to the other question ( a link will do) state what you've tried *(you **have** done that) and make it clear that this is a follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code into:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `db_test`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_proc`(IN newsInfoTable VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN     
    SET @sql_stam = CONCAT( 'SELECT news INTO @news FROM ',newsInfoTable
                           ,' WHERE DATE(`date_time`) = CURDATE()' );      
    PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_stam;         
    SELECT @news;          
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thx @Johan: i change the proce as your direction: SET @sql_stam =CONCAT('SELECT news INTO @news FROM ',newsInfoTable,' WHERE ',CURDATE(),'=?;');    ..But getting new error on SP calling time : Unknown column 'date_time' in 'field list' ..But that field is available into the mentioned table..Hope you give me a solution.