# sql run querys since procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, procedures

I tried do query since one procedure in mysql

I followed the following:

```
DELIMITER #

CREATE PROCEDURE returndata(IN xtable CHAR(255), IN xcolumn CHAR(255))
    BEGIN
        IF (xcolumn = 'XALL') THEN
            SELECT * FROM xtable;
        ELSE
            SELECT xcolumn FROM xtable;
        END IF;
    END;
#

DELIMITER ;
```

but gives error. any help is acceptable, or I might say if this is possible?

EDIT error to call the procedure:

```
MariaDB [pruebab]> CALL returndata('test', 'id');
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'pruebab.xtable' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Can you add the error message your are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are only evaluated in expressions in queries, not where column or table names are required. You need to use a prepared query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE returndata(IN xtable CHAR(255), IN xcolumn CHAR(255))
    BEGIN
        IF (xcolumn = 'XALL') THEN
            SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', xtable);
        ELSE
            SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT ', xcolumn, ' FROM ', xtable);
        END IF;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END;
```

Comment: I really worked, i did not know about the sentence: 

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;

- i will investigate more about it, thx.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a table name as a parameter like that. You need to concatenate the variables into an SQL string to use them. See this answer.

[Mysql stored procedure don't take table name as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609778/mysql-stored-procedure-dont-take-table-name-as-parameter)

Comment: ok, I look like a fool, thanks for your answer.

Comment: No you don't. We're all learning.